# " Decoding failed: Syntax error " in magento when updating the product

Tags: magento-1.9

I got an `error when editing and then updating the weight of product` of only
certain SKU's on backend, and those are downloadable products,While other simple products gets updated easily. I am using magento 1.9.1.0 version.The project resembles wordpress and magento integration too.
The error is :

> Decoding failed: Syntax error

And the update process gets failed. How can I solve this, please help me
out with possible solutions and suggestions.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: HI @sagar sapkota , Have you resolved this issue?. I too get an same issue in my project... Could you help me to fix this issue?